# Is there an another way to handle exceptions instead of "exceptional handling"?

Tags: java, exception

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JDBC {

    public void create(User user) throws SQLException {

        try (
            Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ) {
            statement.setString(1, user.getName());
            statement.setString(2, user.getPassword());
            statement.setString(3, user.getEmail());
            // ...

            int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();

            if (affectedRows == 0) {
                throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no rows affected.");
            }

            try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                    user.setId(generatedKeys.getLong(1));
                }
                else {
                    throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no ID obtained.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception handling was ment for that, to handle exception,
What do you want to do?

Comment: Hello. You should probably explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Try-with-resources just has that syntax. Old Spring's JdbcTemplate wraps it a bit differently, though my preference remains with try-with-resources. Nice code, do not take those downvotes too personally.

Comment: It's "exception handling", not "exceptional handling", which means something rather different.

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling is the only way for handling errors. Depending on the type of application you're writing, you could use a Spring's AOP for example. That would require an extra effort to understand aspect-oriented programing.

The comments are very relevant, maybe you can elaborate on what you are trying to achieve. Explaining that is the best way to find an answer; most likely you will be directed to a whole new solution.

Answer (score 0):

The try-with-resources code is fine, though syntactically indeed a bit ragged.

You might just wrap the code for reuse:

```
public <DTO> void create(DTO dto, DataSource dataSource, String insertSQL,
        BiConsumer<PreparedStatement, DTO> paramSetter,
        BiConsumer<DTO, Long> primaryKeySetter) throws SQLException {
    try (
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL,
                                      Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ) {
        parameterSetter.apply(statement, dto);
        int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();

        if (affectedRows == 0) {
            throw new SQLException("Creating failed, no rows affected.");
        }

        try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                primaryKeySetter.apply(dto, generatedKeys.getLong(1));
            }
            else {
                throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no ID obtained.");
            }
        }
    }
}


create(user, dataSource, SQL_INSERT,
    statement -> {
        statement.setString(1, user.getName());
        statement.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        statement.setString(3, user.getEmail());
    },
    (dto, id) -> dto.setId(id));
```